# Passing value through series of arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I've asked this question before but the answers were not significant to assisting me.

```
    $sql  = 'SELECT `name`, `course`, `id` FROM `teacher` ORDER BY `id` ASC';
    $rows = $mysql_conn->fetch_array($sql);
    // Teacher's Table (id / name / link /course)
    // Course default = 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1

    foreach($rows as $record) { 
        $result[$record['name']] = $record['course']; 
        //$result["Moore,Tyler"] = "1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1";
        //$result["Craig,Joey"]  = "1-2-2-2-1-1-1-1";
        //$result["Degra,Tina"]  = "2-1-1-1-2-1-1-1";
    }

    foreach($result as $teacher=>$courses){
        $result[$teacher] = explode('-',$courses); // Remove -'s from courses and separate the array into sections
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][0] = 1;
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][1] = 2;
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][2] = 2;
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][3] = 2;
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][4] = 1;
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][5] = 1; 
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][6] = 1;
        //$result["Craig,Joey"][7] = 1;
    }

    foreach($result as $teacher=>$courses){
        foreach($courses as $period => $course){
            if($course == $id) { // If course is equal to course page (selected course) record the period 1-8
                $name = explode(',', $teacher); // $name[0] = 'Craig' / $name[1] = 'Joey';
                $result[$period][] = '<a href="?page=teacher&id=">'.$name[0].'<br />'.$name[1].'</a>'; 
                // I want id= to get an id passed to it from the query
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to have the teacher's ID passed through so I can feature it into the link near the bottom of the code.

This is absolutely necessary however I can not seem to figure it all out without my head hurting.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: You should continue following up on your original question, whichever it is, via edits and comments.

Comment: It was quite messy the original, so I thought I would clean it up and repost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the teacher ID to their name:

```
$sql  = 'SELECT CONCAT(`name`, ",", `id`) AS `name`, `course` FROM `teacher` ORDER BY `id` ASC';
```

and then when you explode the teacher's name you will have their ID on index `2` (last name, first name, ID).

Comment: Tell me more about this, would CONCAT join the 2 on output?

Comment: The CONCAT function simply joins two or more strings. So if your teacher's name is "Smith,John" and his ID is 11, CONCAT(name, ",", id) joins the "name" column value, a comma and the "id" column value, making the result "Smith,John,11".

Comment: So when you make _$name = explode(',', $teacher);_, you get the last name on index 0, first name on index 1 just like in your example, but also ID on index 2.

Comment: I was not aware that concatenate could be used in MySQL, I thought it was just an excel thing. Thanks though, you saved me hours of figuring this chaotic problem out.